# Laravel: Get Page views in the last 30 days

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need an output that list page views in the last 30 days.

This is my structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `view_history` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `views` int(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Controller:

```
$pageViews = ViewHistory::where('page_id',1)
                ->select('date','views')
                ->orderBy('date','DESC')
                ->take(30)
                ->get();
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($pageViews as $pageView)
    date: {{$pageView->date}}
    views: {{$pageView->views}}<br>
@endforeach
```

The output to the browser is:

```
date: 2020-05-02 views:10
date: 2020-04-30 views:7
date: 2020-04-26 views:2
date: 2020-04-23 views:12
date: 2020-04-22 views:12
date: 2020-04-21 views:12
date: 2020-04-16 views:6
date: 2020-04-14 views:11
date: 2020-04-12 views:11
date: 2020-04-11 views:1
date: 2020-04-09 views:7
date: 2020-04-07 views:12
date: 2020-04-06 views:6
date: 2020-04-05 views:10
date: 2020-04-04 views:3
date: 2020-04-03 views:6
```

When I dig into the database, I found that some date doesn't have any record in it at all. (Presume 0 views). How go I get all 0 views day to the output as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a new table with all dates and then use leftJoin with this table.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$now = now();
$pageViews = ViewHistory::where('page_id', 1)
    ->select('date', 'views')
    ->whereBetween('date', [$now->toDateString(), $now->copy()->subDays(30)->toDateString()])
    ->get();

$formattedViews = collect();

for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $date = $now->subDay($i)->toDateString();
    $pageView = $pageViews->where('date', $date)->first();
    $formattedViews->add([
        'date' => $date,
        'views' => $pageView ? $pageView->views : 0
    ]);
}
```

then pass `$formattedViews` to your blade file

Comment: eloquent ->get() returns Collection, so you can use all available methods 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-where

Comment: @Hadouken you can mark this as the correct answer if the solution works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can foreach month days instead only the records

```
<?php
$period = Carbon::period(now()->startOfMonth(), now()->endOfMonth());
$pageViews = ViewHistory::where('page_id',1)
                ->select('date','views')
                ->orderBy('date','DESC')
                ->take(30)
                ->get();
// we are foreaching all month days instead of only that you have in database
foreach($period as $date){
    $existing = $pageViews->where('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'));
    $views = $existing ? $existing->views : 0;
    echo sprintf('date: %s views: %d', $date->format('Y-m-d'), $views);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you can do such query after get();

Answer (score 0):

You could youse the map function:

generate a helper with the dates for each day:

```
$start_month_helper = clone $date_start;
    while ($start_month_helper ->lte($date_end)) {
        $days[] = $start_month_helper ->copy()->format('Y-m-d');
        $start_month_helper->addDay();
    }
```

After that you could just map after your query - if there's a matching day add the views, otherwise 0:

```
$data = collect();

ViewHistory::where('page_id',1)
            ->select('date','views')
            ->orderBy('date','DESC')
            ->take(30)
            ->get()
        ->map(function ($item) use($data)  {
            foreach($months as $key => $month) {
                if ($item['date'] === $month) {
                    unset($months[$key]);
                    $data->push($item['views']);
                    return;
                }
                $data->push(0);
                unset($months[$key]);
            }
            return;
        });
```

You now have your data in $data.